# Determining diagonalizability of a matrix containing complex enteries

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$$A=\left[\begin{matrix}3-8i&-11+7i\\-1-4i&-2+6i\end{matrix}\right]$$

I've determined the $tr(A) = 1-2i$, and the $det(A)=3-3i$.

From here I should be able to use the characteristic equation to determine the eigenvalues?

...to solve this am I looking for linearly independent eigenvectors?

$λ^2 −tr(A)λ+det(A)=0$  is our characteristic equation, and $tr(A)=1−2i$  and $det(A)=3−3i$ , so $λ^2 −λ+2iλ+3−3i=0$ ? I feel like I'm on the wrong track...

Comment: Once you find your characteristic equations, you can find your eigenvalues. If your eigenvalues are distinct, then your matrix is diagonalizable. If they aren't, then you need to do a little bit of extra work and find the eigenvectors.

Comment: $\lambda ^2-\mathrm{tr}(A)\lambda+\mathrm{det}(A)=0$ is our characteristic equation, and $\mathrm{tr}(A)=1-2i$ and $\mathrm{det}(A)=3-3i$, so $\lambda ^2-\lambda+2i\lambda+3-3i=0$?  I feel like I'm on the wrong track...

Comment: You are on the right track.

Comment: I got as far as $\frac{{1 - 2i\sqrt { - 15 + 8i} }}{2}$, which was sufficient for the instructor, as solving this is apparently beyond the scope of Linear Algebra 1.  Thanks for the encouragement!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A necessary condition for a complex square matrix to *fail* to be diagonalisable is that its characteristic polynomial have some multiple root. Given that here the characteristic polynomial has degree$~2$, and that the trace (which is the sum of its roots taken with multiplicity) is $\def\ii{\mathbf i}1-2\ii$, this would mean both roots would have to be equal to $\frac12-\ii$, and the determinant (product of the eigenvalues) would need to be $(\frac12-\ii)^2=-\frac34-\ii$. But by inspection that cannot be the case here (I am too lazy to check your computation of the determinant, but it certainly is a [Gaussian integer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integer), which $-\frac34-\ii$ is not).